# Load Web-Content Asynchronously

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, asynchronous

I am trying to load web content asynchronously. I have a large amount of web calls in my viewdidappear method and my app is very unresponsive. I understand the concepts of synchronous and asynchronous loading of content, but don't know how to tell if this is being done asynchronously. The code below is simply embedded in my viewdidappear method, and I assume it is loading synchronously. How would I edit this to make it load asynchronously?  Thank you all!

```
NSString *strURLtwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/json.php?
id=%@&lat1=%@&lon1=%@",id, lat, lon];

NSData *dataURLtwo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURLtwo]];

NSArray *readJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURLtwo options:0 
error:nil];
NSDictionary *element1 = [readJsonArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *name = [element1 objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *address = [element1 objectForKey:@"address"];
NSString *phone = [element1 objectForKey:@"phone"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnectionDelegate:

```
// Your public fetch method
-(void)fetchData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/json.php?id=%@&lat1=%@&lon1=%@",id, lat, lon]];

    // Put that URL into an NSURLRequest
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Create a connection that will exchange this request for data from the URL
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req
                                                 delegate:self
                                         startImmediately:YES];
}
```

Implement the delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Add the incoming chunk of data to the container we are keeping
    // The data always comes in the correct order
    [jsonData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    // All data is downloaded. Do your stuff with the data
    NSArray *readJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization jsonData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *element1 = [readJsonArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *name = [element1 objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *address = [element1 objectForKey:@"address"];
    NSString *phone = [element1 objectForKey:@"phone"];

    jsonData = nil;
    connection = nil;
}

// Show AlertView if error
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    connection = nil;
    jsonData = nil;
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fetch failed: %@", [error     localizedDescription]];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: Thanks superglenn. Am I able to refer to the name, address, and phone NSStrings in my viewdidload/viewdidappear methods? How do I pass that data if its loading asynchronously?

Comment: If you let your viewController be the NSURLConnectionDelegate you will run the fetchData method from the viewDidLoad and then use the data you get (name, address and phone) when it is fetched in the connectionDidFinishLoading. If you create another class to be the delegate, you could use NSNotificationCenter to post the data when its done (and add observer for the notification in you viewController).

Answer (score 1):

For asynchronous web content loading, I recommend you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/) . It'll solve lots of your major headache of networking in future. How to do:

1) subclass AFHTTPCLient, for example:

```
//WebClientHelper.h
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface WebClientHelper : AFHTTPClient{

}

+(WebClientHelper *)sharedClient;

@end

//WebClientHelper.m
#import "WebClientHelper.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"

NSString *const gWebBaseURL = @"http://whateverBaseURL.com/";


@implementation WebClientHelper

+(WebClientHelper *)sharedClient
{
    static WebClientHelper * _sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gWebBaseURL]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    return self;
}
@end
```

2) Request asynchronously your web content, put this code in any relevant part

```
    NSString *testNewsURL = @"http://whatever.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:testNewsURL];
    NSURLRequest *request  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationHttp =
    [[WebClientHelper sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSString *szResponse = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
         NSLog(@"Response: %@", szResponse );

         //PUT your code here
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Operation Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }];

    [[WebClientHelper sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operationHttp];
```